# No libraries upon compilation [LWJGL]

Tags: java, native, lwjgl

I have set up my libraries correctly as far as I can tell with NetBeans. I am able to run the application from inside the IDE without any issues, but after I compile the files and attempt to run the jar, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.libr
ary.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
        at gui.Screen.init(Screen.java:25)
        at gui.Screen.open(Screen.java:35)
        at Solitude.main(Solitude.java:22)
```

I am sure it has something to do with natives, but I had no luck finding anything to resolve my issue after an hour of searching.

Comment: Try to set the system property `-Djava.library.path=` of your java application to refer to the relative folder of your project where the lwjgl library can be found. Do this when running your application from the command line. Or, if you are using Eclipse, you can do this in the VM arguments list in Eclipse Run Configuration for your application. For example: `-Djava.library.path=lib` to refer to the `lib` folder

Answer (score 0):

You are missing libraries from your classpath.  Your IDE knows where they are, but the jar doesn't.  How you fix this depends on how you build and distribute your jar.

If you want to package it all in one jar, check your manifest and make sure the libraries are both listed there AND were included in the files zipped into the jar.